Not getting redirected to the desired page
My problem is that, when I click the button that has <Nav.Link href='#Resources'>..., or any other link for that matter, nothing happens. I don't get redirected. But If I write http://localhost:3000/resources in the url, I do get redirected to the correct page. Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?
I have this code to create the menus
import { Stack, Button, DropdownButton, Dropdown, Navbar, Nav, Container, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import dk from './flags/dk.png';
import eng from './flags/eng.png';
import es from './flags/es.png';
import fr from './flags/fr.png';
import de from './flags/de.png';
import se from './flags/se.png';

const Menus = () => {
    const langs = [
        { name: 'English', id: 'eng', iconURL: eng },
        { name: 'Danish', id: 'dk', iconURL: dk },
        { name: 'Swedish', id: 'se', iconURL: se },
        { name: 'French', id: 'fr', iconURL: fr },
        { name: 'Spanish', id: 'es', iconURL: es },
        { name: 'German', id: 'de', iconURL: de }
    ];    
    
    const itemAr = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) {        
        itemAr[i] = <NavDropdown.Item href='#'>{langs[i].name}<img style={{float: 'right'}} src={langs[i].iconURL} alt='ccc' /></NavDropdown.Item>            
    }

    return(   
        <>
        <div className='menuDiv1'>
            <Navbar bg='dark' variant='dark' expand='lg' sticky='top'>
                <Container>
                    <Navbar.Brand href='#Home'>Language Exchange</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='basic-navbar-nav' />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
                    <Nav className='basic-nav-dropdown'>            
                        <div>                                        
                            <Stack direction='horizontal' gap={1}>
                                <Nav.Link href='#Home'><Button variant='light'>Home</Button></Nav.Link>
                                <DropdownButton variant='light' title='Languages'>                                        
                                    {itemAr}
                                </DropdownButton>
                                <Nav.Link href='#Resources'><Button variant='light'>Resources</Button></Nav.Link>
                                <Nav.Link href='#Contact'><Button variant='light'>Contact</Button></Nav.Link>                                
                            </Stack>
                        </div>
                    </Nav> 
                    </Navbar.Collapse>                
                </Container>
            </Navbar>            
        </div>
        </>
        
    )
}

export default Menus;

And the code below is for the routes.
import './Site.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Menus from './Menus';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Contact from './Contact';
import Resources from './Resources';
import PageNotFound from './PageNotFound';

const App = () => {        
    return (
         
            <>        
            <Menus />
            <div className='mainContentDiv'>      
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route index element={<Home />}></Route>                                                     
                        <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />}></Route>
                        <Route path='/resources' element={<Resources />}></Route>
                        <Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound />}></Route>
                    </Routes>                    
                </BrowserRouter>               
                
            </div> 
            </>        
            
    );
}

export default App;

And here is just an example of how one of the pages looks, that should be redirected to, once one clicks on the menus. In this case, it's the Resources page

You are using wrong syntax for 'href'. Passing a string prefixed by a '#' means you wont to move/scroll to a section/element whose id is after the '#' i.e in your case 'Resource' or 'Contact'. Whereas if, you want to change the location of current window i.e move the user to new page/url. Then refactor the href to href="/resources", and href="/contact". Also for homepage, you need to set href="/". For more clarity, look here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp.

@MohsinMurad Thanks mate, that was it. I just got the use of the # from a tutorial, where they used that.  It was explained why the had the #, so I thought that was the way to do it.
I will accept your answer as the solution, if you make it possible

You are using wrong syntax for href. Passing a string prefixed by a '#' means you wont to move/scroll to a section/element whose id is after the '#' i.e in your case 'Resource' or 'Contact'. Whereas if, you want to change the location of current window i.e move the user to new page/url. Then refactor the href to href="/resources" for 'resources' page, and href="/contact" for 'contact' page. Also for homepage, you need to set href="/". For more clarity, look here.
